# Efficient subsetting and averaging

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

The following code aims to average 4 groups of the `values` vector. Which elements belong to each group is determined by the `indic` vector and two split variables `x1, x2`:

- Group 1: those elements where `indic` is between 0 and x1,
- Group 2: those elements where `indic` is between x1 and x2,

and so on. The correspondence between the `values` vector and the `indic` is by position in the vector.

As a result, the code returns a list of the same length as values with the corresponding averages.

```
(* Input variables *)
indic = RandomChoice[Range[1,100], 1000];
values= RandomReal[{0,10}, 1000];

(* given certain breaks on indic, I want to calculate average on the values *)
myfun[x1_, x2_]:= Module[{avgVal, breaks, setAvg},
    avgVal=ConstantArray[Missing, Length[values]];
    breaks={0, x1,x2, Max[indic]};
    setAvg[i_]:=Module[{idx, a},
        idx=Position[indic, x_/;(x>breaks[[i]]&&x<=breaks[[i+1]])];
        a=Mean[Extract[values,idx]];
        avgVal=ReplacePart[avgVal, idx -> a]
    ];
    setAvg /@ Range[1,3];
    Return[avgVal];
];

myfun[20,50] (* averages values where indic < 20, between 20 and 50 and >50 *)
```

Minimal example:

```
indic  = {2,3,5,6,3,6,7,4};
values = Range[3,10];
x1=3;
x2=6;
```

Hence group 1 is the first, second, fifth element, group 2 comprises the third and the last element, and group 3 are the remaining elements.

The mean of group 1 is Mean[3,4,7]= 14/3, of group 2 is Mean[5,10]=15/2 and of group 3 the mean is Mean[6,8,9]=23/3. That is why myfun[x1,x2] should return

```
{14/3, 14/3, 15/2, 23/3, 14/3, 23/3, 23/3, 15/2}
```

I would like to discuss how to make this code faster. Is there a more Mathematica-like way to do it? Especially, I suspect the `ReplacePart` calls to be slow. Is there a way around it?

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Why don´t you describe in more detail what you want to do? Having to reverse-engineer your code is not so attractive.

Comment: Sorry, there were errors in the code. I also edited the problem description.

Comment: There may be a more efficient way, but is this on the right track?: `{Pick[values, indic, x_ /; 0 < x < 3], Pick[values, indic, x_ /; 3 < x < 6]}`.  It's unclear what to do about the boundaries x1, x2, and what to do with the result, without the reverse-engineering Yves mentions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Pick` have not heard of it until now. The problem for me is to write the average vector. Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
indic = RandomChoice[Range[1, 10], 100];
values = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];
xIntervals = {0, 3, 5, 8, Infinity};

pos = Position[indic, x_ /; (#1 <= x < #2)] & @@@ Partition[xIntervals, 2, 1];
l = Extract[values, #] & /@ pos;
means = Replace[l, {x__} :> ConstantArray[Mean@{x}, Length@{x}], {1}];
values1 = values;
(values1[[#1]] = #2) & @@@ Transpose[{Flatten@pos, Flatten@means}];
```

and now you have your desired result in `values1`

Comment: You need to take care of the comparison limits `(#1 <= x <= #2)`. I don't know how you want to handle the extremes

Comment: This is about 15% faster than my code. I never saw `Replace` in use before. Thank you!

Comment: @KarstenW. I didn't care about speed because you mentioned 1000 items. Perhaps I can improve it

Comment: @KarstenW. And I'm stupid and haven't read your last sentence

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Especially the way you use `indic` to set the outer bounds. For instance, note that it's not guaranteed that `Max[indic]` is larger than `x2`.

Anyway, the following might nonetheless be of use:

```
values = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 6];

myfun[n_, m_][values_] := Module[{split},
  split = {values[[;; n]], values[[n + 1 ;; m]], values[[m + 1 ;;]]};
  Flatten[ConstantArray[Mean[#], Length[#]] & /@ split]
];

myfun[2, 4][values]
```

> `{5.46557, 5.46557, 8.48547, 8.48547, 7.14661, 7.14661}`

Note that your output will be different due to randomness of `values`.

**Edit:** If it's ok to have a balanced sampling, you could try *random sampling* as follows:

```
values = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 10];
range = Range[Length[values]];

(* get three sample with balanced sample size *)
numSamples = 3;
size = Ceiling[Length[range]/numSamples];
samples = Partition[RandomSample[range], size, size, {1, 1}, {}];

(* define a dictionary that associates each index with an appropriate mean *)
means =
  Rule @@ # & /@
    Transpose@{#, ConstantArray[Mean@values[[#]], Length@values[[#]]]} & /@
      samples // Association;

(* output *)
means /@ range
```

> `{5.24007, 4.63392, 5.24007, 5.5112, 4.63392, 5.5112}`

Let me know if I need to unpack the definition for `means`.

Comment: I'd like a vector of the same length as `values`, how can I do this?

Comment: @KarstenW. I edited the answer. Is this closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: The output looks now as desired, however I do not really understand the `samples` variable.

Comment: `samples` is a partitioned version of the randomly shuffled version of `range`, where `range` contains the indices for `values`. In other words, `Sort[Join @@ samples]` gives back `range`.